# Ordered model in Cassandra 2.0

Tags: database, database-design, nosql, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I'm pretty new in Cassandra and I am trying to make a model for time series data. My current proposal is this:

```
CREATE TABLE myproject.variables (
nearest_10_minutes timestamp,
variable_type text,
value double,
variable_timestamp timestamp, 
PRIMARY KEY((variable_type, nearest_10_minutes), variable_timestamp)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (variable_timestamp ASC);
```

The `variable_timestamp` is the actual time when the `value` is sensed. The `nearest_10_minutes` is the timestamp, but rounded to the nearest 10 minutes. For example if the variable_timestamp is: `19/11/2013 13:13:19.562`, the nearest_10_minutes is `19/11/2013 13:10:00.000`

I can get rid of the variable_type in the cluster key and put it into a secondary index, but I'm not sure does that aid my case.

The issue is that I'm not really sure how to properly order data. If I take a `select * from myproject.variables` (just for testing purposes), I get something like (timestamps showed only):

```
Tue Nov 19 13:19:52 CET 2013
Tue Nov 19 13:19:55 CET 2013
Tue Nov 19 13:40:04 CET 2013
Tue Nov 19 13:40:14 CET 2013
Tue Nov 19 13:40:29 CET 2013
...
Tue Nov 19 13:49:58 CET 2013
Tue Nov 19 13:49:59 CET 2013
...
Tue Nov 19 14:30:00 CET 2013
Tue Nov 19 14:30:01 CET 2013
```

Now, I'm not really clear should I get some default ordering or not? If I use a `select * from myproject.variables order by variable_timestamp asc` then I get an error stating I may only use ORDER BY if the partition key is filtered with EQ or IN. And IN can only be used with the second portion of the partition key, not the first one.

All in all, I'm a bit confused, how can I model this in a way I can select and order my data?

------------------------------Answer:------------------------------------

So in a way all the current answers by jorgebg and BryceAtNetwork23 and comments from  Mikhail Stepura have shown me the path I consider right. Since I wanted to keep the partitioning as random as possible but in a way that I can predict it so I can have ordered queries and use the IN keyword (so I can put multiple partition keys in the query), I just decided to make a custom partitioning key. The scheme I chose is concatenating variable_type:timestamp_rounded_by_the_hour. That introduces some client leaking of the storage logic, I know, but it is fairly easy to recreate the set of partitioning keys on query in the code.

The answer I chose was the one that contributed the most.

Comment: Also, you can have composite partition keys in CQL (without the need to contatenate them) http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2013/01/11/primary-keys-in-cql.html

Comment: True, but then I cannot use the IN keyword with all of the parts of the partition key except the last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clustering order affects how the rows are stored (and retrieved) **within the same partition key**, not how all the rows inside the column family are stored (partitioned).

In your case, the rows retrieved from the following query will be ordered by `variable_timestamp`:

```
SELECT * FROM variables WHERE variable_type = ? AND nearest_10_minutes = ?;
```

But if you retrieve multiple partition keys:

```
SELECT * FROM variables;
```

It will be ordered by the partition key (the generated token of the partition key) and then by the clustering key.

You can see how rows and columns are stored and partitioned in the blog post [CQL3 for Cassandra experts](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3-for-cassandra-experts).

Comment: Thanks, I realized that at the time you posted the answer. Now I am having trouble getting out of this situation. I understand the problem, but what now?

Comment: Actually the partition key just helps to determine which node the row ends up on.  It does not affect sort order.

Comment: @Alexander.S you have to model your schema based on queries you plan to execute. So, what will be your queries?

Comment: As I already wrote in another comment, my most important (if not the only) query would be like this: Slect variable_timestamp, value from myproject.variables where variable_timestamp > <time1> and variable_timestamp < <time2> order by variable_timestamp. Of course, this is more SQL than CQL but this is just for description.

Comment: One of the answers above recomends ``PRIMARY KEY(variable_type, variable_timestamp)``, then you would be able to run ``Slect variable_timestamp, value from myproject.variables where value_type = 'key' AND variable_timestamp > <time1> and variable_timestamp < <time2>``. You don't need ORDER BY, because data will be already stored in ordered manner

Comment: And your data MUST be in a single partition (physical row) to be ordered, so you have to restrict the partition key somehow (either ``=`` or ``IN``)

Comment: Ok, but doesn't that lead to bad partitioning, since a lot of values will be stored on a same node with the same variable_type? And if I have a lot of entries then the row will be very big. Then I will need to shard it, and todo that then I need a metadata table to keep the ranges (which time span is on which row for that variable_type). And to be able to use IN and multiple variables I'll have to programatically make for example "myvariabletype-1" partition key. Does all of that seem legit? Especially the part with the sharding since the sharding logic will be client-side?

Comment: I derived some sort of solution, and I believe it is a relatively correct way, correct me if I am wrong. I explained the answer in the original question for future notice.

Answer (score 2):

```
PRIMARY KEY((variable_type, nearest_10_minutes), variable_timestamp)
```

The best values for a PRIMARY/Partitioning key are ones that are unique.  How unique is `variable_type`?  Just based on what you've said here (without really knowing your data), it sounds like `value` might make a better candidate.

```
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (variable_timestamp ASC);
```

"Now, I'm not really clear should I get some default ordering or not?"

Unless I missed something, it looks like your data is coming back in ascending order.  Check through DataStax's documentation on [clustering order](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3-evolutions).  With the way you have your PRIMARY KEY defined right now, it will enforce a clustering order on `variable_timestamp`, ascending.  You should only need to specify `CLUSTERING ORDER` if you need that order reversed.  Note that your clustering key(s) indicate the order in which the data is stored on disk.

"I get an error stating I may only use ORDER BY if the partition key is filtered with EQ or IN."

Right, because CQL won't just let you specify any columns in your WHERE or ORDER BY.  If you want to do anything with the clustering key(s) (in the ORDER BY or WHERE), you need to also specify the partition key(s) (in the WHERE clause, in this case).

Try creating your PRIMARY KEY like this:

```
PRIMARY KEY(value, variable_timestamp)
```

Or if after evaluating your model `variable_type` still makes sense:

```
PRIMARY KEY(variable_type, variable_timestamp)
```

And don't add the `CLUSTERING ORDER` clause.

For more help on modeling time series data, check out [DataStax Academy](https://datastaxacademy.elogiclearning.com/)'s (free) course called "Java Development With Apache Cassandra". Session 5, Module 104 discusses modeling a simple time series.  See if that helps.

Comment: The value is fairly unique, since it is a sensor information, it may repeat sometimes. The variable_timestamp is unique per variable_type. My biggest concern is reading, the data is read sequentially in a period from time t1 to t2 (I'm replaying the values) and that is where I need the ORDER BY. I will not need the value in my query, but I will need the variable_type.
P.S The variable type is not that unique. It is a fixed set.